# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I know there are several thread on this issue, but I had tried the suggestions and still can't get pass this.  I put the file in the path; I remove Local and change secure-file-priv="";  I grant file privilege; I even play with format of the path.  Still give me error.

---

The database and the file is on the server.

MySQL path is c:/program files/MySQL/MySQL server 5.7

data path is e:/program files/MySQL/data

upload path is e:/program file/MySQL/uploads

LOAD DATA  INFILE 'E:\Program Files\MySQL\uploads\file.txt' INTO TABLE concept LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES

---

I even try to load on the command line.  Of course, I got another error even with grant privilege.

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

---

I have the same setup on my local machine.  I have No problem...

Any idea I should try next beside shooting my computer?

Comment: Did you try `'E:/Program Files/MySQL/uploads/file.txt'` ?

Comment: Yes I sure did.